# Apscheduler cron to start twice a day

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I want to start the test twice a day, 3 am and 9 am.

What value I should set in "hour"? 3-9 start test every hour.

```
@scheduler.task("cron", id="program_healtcheck", day_of_week="*", hour=?)
```

Comment: Can you try `hour="15,21"`?

Comment: did this comment help ?